# ListView muito lento para carregar XML

Tags: android

Está demorando muito para carregar poucos itens, demora vários segundos, e para carregar muitos itens, nunca carrega. Usei o mesmo algoritmo de leitura de XML, com uma lista simples e carregou bem rápido, porém no meu ListView personalizado demora bastante, já tentei usar ViewHolder, porém não funcionou. Vejam minhas classes:

**Adapter**

```
public class AdapterSegmento extends BaseAdapter {


private ArrayList<Segmento> itens;
private Activity myContext;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
public AdapterSegmento(Context context, ArrayList<Segmento> itens) {
    //Itens que preencheram o listview
    this.itens = itens;
    //responsavel por pegar o Layout do item.

}

/**
 * Retorna a quantidade de itens
 *
 * @return
 */
public int getCount() {
    return itens.size();
}

/**
 * Retorna o item de acordo com a posicao dele na tela.
 *
 * @param position
 * @return
 */
public Segmento getItem(int position) {
    return itens.get(position);
}

/**
 * Sem implementaÃ§Ã£o
 *
 * @param position
 * @return
 */

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


static class ViewHolder{
    TextView tvName;
    TextView tvDescription;
    ImageView imagem;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

  View vi = view;             //trying to reuse a recycled view
  ViewHolder holder = null;

  if (vi == null) {
      //The view is not a recycled one: we have to inflate
      vi = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.empresa_item, parent, false);
      holder = new ViewHolder();

      holder.tvName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.nomeEmpresa);
      holder.tvDescription = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.subtitulo);
     // holder.imagem = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imagemSegmento);
      vi.setTag(holder);
  } else {
      // View recycled !
      // no need to inflate
      // no need to findViews by id
      holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
  }

 Segmento item = itens.get(position);

 holder.tvName.setText(item.getNome());
 holder.tvDescription.setText(item.getSubtitulo());
     return vi;
}
}
```

**Minha View**

```
public class SegmentoView extends Util implements OnItemClickListener {

private ListView listView;
private AdapterSegmento adapterEmpresa;
private ArrayList<Segmento> itensEmpresa;
XmlReader reader;
String URL;
ProgressDialog dialog;

@SuppressLint("NewApi") @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // carrega o layout onde contem o ListView
    setContentView(R.layout.empresa_lista);
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.hide();


    //Carregar XML
    reader = new XmlReader("http://www.itcuties.com/feed/");



    itensEmpresa = new ArrayList<Segmento>();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.getItems().size(); ++i) {
            Segmento segmento = new Segmento();

            segmento.setNome(reader.getItems().get(i).getNome());
            segmento.setLink(reader.getItems().get(i).getLink());

            itensEmpresa.add(segmento);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    // Cria o adapter
    adapterEmpresa = new AdapterSegmento(this, itensEmpresa);

    // Define o Adapter
    listView.setAdapter(adapterEmpresa);
    // Cor quando a lista Ã© selecionada para ralagem.
    listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);

}
}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Não seria melhor usar um vetor de strings para fazer as opções do ListView?

Comment: Eu fiz isso agora, mudei no adapter e e na view para Segmento[] itens;   e deu na mesma.

Comment: Alguma ideia? alguem?

Comment: Coloca uma gratificação na pergunta. É o meio lícito de chamar atenção.

Comment: nao entendi, como assim?

Comment: Coloque uma gratificação/recompensa/bounty na sua pergunta. Vai lhe custar reputação, mas ela fica valendo mais :D

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19750/discussion-between-war-lock-and-mutley).

Comment: Já considerou usar AsyncTask?

Comment: Eu não sei usar, se poder me mostrar como resposta como ficaria no meu contexto agradeceria muito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Causa**

A lentidão no seu caso se dá pelo de a cada iteração no seguinte trecho:

```
for (int i = 0; i < reader.getItems().size(); ++i) {
    // código omitido
}
```

Pois a cada iteração o método `reader.getItems().size()` é chamado para ser comparado com o `i`, e a cada chamada feita ao método `reader.getItems` uma consulta na Web é realizada.

**Solução**

Ao invés de chamar tal método utilize uma variável para armazenar o retorno de `reader.getItems` e assim o tamanho dessa lista pode ser usada no `for`. Ficando assim:

```
items = reader.getItems();
itensEmpresa = new ArrayList<Segmento>();
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i) {
        Segmento segmento = new Segmento();

        segmento.setNome(items.get(i).getNome());
        segmento.setLink(items.get(i).getLink());

        itensEmpresa.add(segmento);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Você colocou o AsyncTask pra executar dentro do Adapter?

Comment: Perguntei poque você disse "do adapter para receber um asynctask", acho que não entendi bem então.

Comment: Estranho acontecer um NullPointerException... o ArrayList está inicializado quando passando no construtor do Adapter.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19773/discussion-between-war-lock-and-luidne).

Comment: Você não pode executar uma AsyncTask a partir de um Adapter. Você deve executá—la a partir da MainThread, ou seja, uma Activity que no seu caso é a classe SegmentoView.

Comment: @War Lock podemos conversar pelo Hangout? É que estou acessando pelo celular pois só tenho internet nele no momento.

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Coloque NULL onde está parent

ANTES

```
 vi = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.empresa_item, parent, false);
```

DEPOIS

```
 vi = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.empresa_item, null, false);
```

Você também pode trocar essa linha por:

```
 vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext(), R.layout.empresa_item, null);
```

Depois, você pode verificar o tempo que gasta para essa linha:

```
//Carregar XML
    reader = new XmlReader("http://www.itcuties.com/feed/");
```

Usando Log, por exemplo:

```
 Log.d("teste",  new Date());
//Carregar XML
    reader = new XmlReader("http://www.itcuties.com/feed/");
Log.d("teste", new Date());
```

Obviamente, você pode obter um tempo melhor no lugar desse new Date() que usei, mas foi só para exemplificar. Talvez o gargalo esteja aí.

Você pode usar AsyncTask ou AsyncTaskLoader  para realizar esse carregamento.

Aqui você confere como usar AsyncTask:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Aqui você confere como usar AsyncTaskLoader:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html

Estuda AndroidAnnotations.

http://androidannotations.org/

É ainda melhor que o padrão ViewHolder ;)

Usando Annotations na sua Activity aí, para você ter uma ideia, nem precisaria de AsyncTask, pois ficaria assim:

```
ProgressDialog dialog;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // carrega o layout onde contem o ListView
    setContentView(R.layout.empresa_lista);
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.hide();

     // Cor quando a lista Ã© selecionada para ralagem.
    listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);


    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Carregando dados...");
    dialog.show();

     //chamada para carregamento dos dados
     loadData();
}


@Background
void loadData(){

    //Carregar XML
    XmlReader reader = new XmlReader("http://www.itcuties.com/feed/");

    ArrayList itensEmpresa = new ArrayList<Segmento>();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.getItems().size(); ++i) {
            Segmento segmento = new Segmento();

            segmento.setNome(reader.getItems().get(i).getNome());
            segmento.setLink(reader.getItems().get(i).getLink());

            itensEmpresa.add(segmento);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


@UIThread
void createAdapter(ArrayList<Segmento> items){

    // Cria o adapter
    adapterEmpresa = new AdapterSegmento(this, items);
    // Define o Adapter
    listView.setAdapter(adapterEmpresa);

    dialog.dismiss();


}
```

(se tiver algum erro aí em cima, dá um desconto, pois eu não coloquei isso pra compilar XD)

Comment: Fiz as alterações basicas que vc passou, e nada, usei anotations e nada, mandei mostrar com log a linha do reader, e foi bem rapido, porem la dentro do for, demora 10 segundos pra cada iteração da lista.

Comment: Então você sabe que o gargalo está nesse for.  Para começar a otimizar, tente fazer uma atribuição para um objeto logo no início, para essa linha:  reader.getItems().get(i), ao invés de fazer isso duas vezes.  A operação de .get(i) , sabemos que a complexidade é O(1), mas talvez, getItems() não seja.